# dockerfile cant find entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

### My filesystem:

- Dockerfile
- entrypoint.sh
- package.json
- /shared_volume/

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8


# Create and define the node_modules's cache directory.
RUN mkdir /usr/src/cache
WORKDIR /usr/src/cache

COPY . .
RUN npm install

# Create and define the application's working directory.
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# entrypoint to copy the node_modules and root files into /usr/src/app, to be shared with my local volume.
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/cache/entrypoint.sh"]
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo hello world start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

### entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r /usr/src/cache/. /usr/src/app/.
```

### command line - bash script

If I run this code (note: using windows 10 with cmder, hence %cd% not pwd):

```
docker run -it --rm -v %cd%/shared_volume:/app --privileged shared-volume-example bash
```

### Error

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

If I take out the reference to entrypoint, then the code works, so what is going on with the entrypoint?

Any suggestions.
thanks

Comment: Does your base image actually include `/bin/bash`?  Many lighter-weight images (especially those based on Alpine) don’t; but if you limit yourself to the POSIX shell language (your script looks fine) then changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh` might help.  Also check that the script is executable.

Comment: thanks. Yeah tried that. Same problem. Just wondering if - from: node doesnt include any bash at all?

Answer (score 0):

ok someone else posted an answer regarding line endings.  I used atom line-ending-selector and set it to LF in replacement, and resaved the file and now it works.